# how to make this texarea javascript work in other browsers except Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

Please can someone help me out on this

this is a JavaScript code that inserts a particular bbcode say [b] [/b] in a textarea box when the user clicks on it like it is in V Bulletin and SMF forums, when the user clicks on an image with **B** [b][/b] appears in the textarea form,

now i made mine to work though am not good in JavaScript
but the problem is that it only works in **INTERNET EXPLORER** and doesn't work in OPERA and Mozilla 
so I need help to make it work in other browser apart from IE

```
<HTML>
 <Head>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var isSelected = false;

 function copySelection(workArea){

 workArea.workText = document.selection.createRange();
 isSelected = true;
 }

 function wrapInTags(workArea,isTag){

 if (isSelected)
 {
 workArea.workText.text = "["+isTag+"]"+workArea.workText.text+"[/"+isTag+"]";
 if (workArea.workText.text==''){isSelected=false;workArea.focus()}
 }
 }

 function AddURL(workArea){

 var AddURL="";
 var txt="";


 txt=prompt("Enter URL for the link.","http://");
 AddURL="[.url="+txt+"]";
 AddURL2="[./url]";


 if (isSelected)
 {
 workArea.workText.text = AddURL+workArea.workText.text+AddURL2;
 if (workArea.workText.text==''){isSelected=false;workArea.focus()}
 }

 }

 </Script>
 </Head>


 <Body>
 <Form name='Form1' method=post action='process.php'>
 <textarea name='area1' cols='40' rows='4' onselect="copySelection(this)"></textarea><br>
 <input type=button value='Italic' onclick="wrapInTags(this.form.area1,'i')">
 <input type=button value='Bold' onclick="wrapInTags(this.form.area1,'b')">
 <input type=button value='Underline' onclick="wrapInTags(this.form.area1,'u')">
 <input type=button value='Link' onclick="AddURL(this.form.area1)">
 <br><br>
 <input type=submit value='Submit'>
 </Form>


 </Body>
 </HTML>
```

Comment: check this it may help http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=601831

Answer (score 1):

*document.selection* and all its methods and propierties are IE only, but there is other things that work well on other browsers.

```
var isSelected = false;

function copySelection(workArea){
    workArea.workText = document.selection ? document.selection.createRange() : {text:workArea.value.substring(workArea.selectionStart,workArea.selectionEnd)};
    workArea.offsetSelection = workArea.selectionStart;
    isSelected = true;
}


function wrapInTags(workArea,isTag){
    if (isSelected)
        {
        if(document.selection){ 
            workArea.workText.text = "["+isTag+"]"+workArea.workText.text+"[/"+isTag+"]";
        } else {        
            workArea.value = 
                workArea.value.substring(0,workArea.offsetSelection)
                + "["+isTag+"]"+workArea.workText.text+"[/"+isTag+"]" 
                + workArea.value.substring(workArea.offsetSelection+workArea.workText.text.length)
        }


        if (workArea.workText.text==''){
            isSelected=false;workArea.focus()
        }
    }
}


function AddURL(workArea){
    var AddURL="";
    var txt="";

    txt=prompt("Enter URL for the link.","http://");
    AddURL="[.url="+txt+"]";
    AddURL2="[./url]";

    if (isSelected) {
        if(document.selection){ 
            workArea.workText.text = AddURL+workArea.workText.text+AddURL2;
        } else {
            workArea.value = 
                workArea.value.substring(0,workArea.offsetSelection)
                +  AddURL +workArea.workText.text+ AddURL2
                + workArea.value.substring(workArea.offsetSelection+workArea.workText.text.length)
        }

        if (workArea.workText.text==''){
            isSelected=false;workArea.focus()
        }
    }

}
```

The solution that david pointed out also works well.